# How do I ngShow and ngHide two different elements at the same time with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

So I have two elements that are exclusive:

```
<span>foo</span>
<span>bar</span>
```

And I added ngShow and ngHide to them:

```
<span ng-show="fooTime">foo</span>
<span ng-hide="fooTime">bar</span>
```

But now when these render, there is a split second where they both show.

How can I make them show/hide at the same time?

Comment: Can you use ng-show="fooTime" and ng-show="!fooTime". Its possible that angular renders all ng-show and then all ng-hides.

Comment: That code will have the same problem... angular just goes in order, it doesn't pick certain tags to render first.  The root cause is that there are two different watches here, which could run in any order; the given answer only has a single watch, so the elements will always update together.

Answer (score 4):

**Use a ngSwitch rather than an ngShow/ngHide:**

```
<span ng-switch="fooTime">
    <span ng-switch-when="true">foo</span>
    <span ng-switch-when="false">bar</span>
</span>
```

**Why?**

When using the separate ngShow/ngHides, each element is getting a separate $watch which execute asynchronously leaving the potential for a gap between the events. By using ngSwitch, only one $watch is setup so they must render at the same time.

**How I got to ngSwitch?**

On my first attempt, I realized the watches were not tied together, so I resorted to letting CSS tie the changes together:

```
<style>
    [first] .fooTime {
        display: inline;
    }
    [second] .fooTime, [first] {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<span ng-class="{'fooTime':fooTime}">
    <span first>foo</span>
    <span second>bar</span>
</span>
```

But ngSwitch is much more clean.

Edit: 
It seems ngSwitch [triggers enter and leave animations](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate#usage) so if you are using ngAnimate, there is a default of a .2 second transition. I haven't found a way around this yet.

Comment: This doesn't work for me :( it has the same problem as using ng-show (the elements exist at the same time for a split second). I suppose it is the enter/leave animations that you are talking about?

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. I am trying to use it with Ionic, to show one button but then show an ion-spinner when the button is tapped. They both show up for a split second when using ng-show or ng-switch.

Comment: The `ng-switch` approach did not work for me but the `ng-class` approach did so upvoting

Comment: To solution to the 200ms transition is to add styling to override it. This is a generic solution that excludes browser prefixes and targets `ngSwitchWhen` (which should be altered based on your use case: `[ng-switch-when] { transition-duration: 0s; }`.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem pretty elegantly with some CSS.

```
*[ng-switch] *[ng-switch-when] + *[ng-switch-when], 
*[ng-switch] *[ng-switch-when] + *[ng-switch-default] {
        display: none;
}
```

This uses the wildcard selector (*) and attribute selector for ng-switch-when to make this a general solution that should work in any instance where ng-switch is used.

Answer (score 0):

Upvoted and commented on @eternalmatt's answer ... here is my solution based on the `css` part of his solution. In my experience `ng-swtich` will not solve this problem. I am using `scss` but you can convert `scss` to `css` here http://www.sassmeister.com/. The template of my button directive that toggles button text and ajax spinner based on the value of `showSpinner`.

template

```
<button class="fin-button no-outline" ng-class="{disabled: state==='disabled'}" ng-click="action()">
  <span ng-class="{'showSpinner': showSpinner}">
    <span class="text-first" fin-button-text>{{text}}</span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat spinner" fin-button-spinner></span>
  </span>
</button>
```

scss

```
.fin-button {
    [fin-button-text] {
        display: inline;
    }
    [fin-button-spinner] {
        display: none
    }
    .showSpinner {
        [fin-button-text] {
            display: none;
        }
        [fin-button-spinner] {
            display: inline;
        }
    }
}
```

css .. generated from conversion via the above link

```
.fin-button [fin-button-text] {
  display: inline;
}

.fin-button [fin-button-spinner] {
  display: none;
}

.fin-button .showSpinner [fin-button-text] {
  display: none;
}

.fin-button .showSpinner [fin-button-spinner] {
  display: inline;
}
```

and is `here be dragons` comment that I have above the scss in my code

```
// .... HERE BE DRAGONS ... ///
    // The following is used to hide show the spinner or the
    // button text. Needs to be done like this because ng-hide, ng-show,
    // ng-if, and ng-switch all put seperate watches even if you are conditioning
    // on the same vairable ... see this SO // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20341288/how-do-i-ngshow-and-nghide-two-different-elements-at-the-same-time-with-angularj
```