# Changing text in addition to another content depending on ngShow and ngHide in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I browsed those two answered questions related to mine 
[Angular JS ngShow and ngHide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28195465/angular-js-ngshow-and-nghide) /
[How do I ngShow and ngHide two different elements at the same time with AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20341288/how-do-i-ngshow-and-nghide-two-different-elements-at-the-same-time-with-angularj), however, I couldn't get my code working.

I have a form and if clicked show I want the form to be shown with the text hide, and respectively, when hide clicked I want the form to be hidden with the text show

**HTML**

```
<div class="formMessage">
    Say Hello
</div>

<div class='assertive formHideShow' ng-click="hider = !hider" ng-class="{ active: hider }">
    <span>{{text}}</span>
</div>

<div class="formForm" ng-show="hider">
    <div class="list">
        <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label">Name</span>
            <input type="text">
        </label>

        <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label">Email</span>
            <input type="text">
        </label>

        <label class="marginTop item item-input">
            <textarea class='formTextArea' placeholder="Your thoughts go here"></textarea>
        </label>

        <button class="button button-block button-balanced">
            Submit
        </button>
    </div>                          
</div>
```

**APP.JS**

```
$scope.hider = true;

if($scope.hider = true) {
    $scope.text='show';
} else {
    $scope.text='hide';
}
```

So far it doesn't matter whether the form is shown or not, the text always stays show

Comment: Can you put what you've attempted into a JSFiddle or Plunker? It's hard to know if you've just missed a critical step or if there's something more complex at play.

Comment: the idea provided in the answer perfectly worked for me, thanks for the comment, though

Answer (score 0):

Here is a real simple example of what i think you're trying to do

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/vweNr1Dx20DE8GOcvoNY?p=preview)

Basically i changed teh controller a bit

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("appCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope){
  $scope.isHidden = true;

  $scope.text = function(){
    return ($scope.isHidden ? "Show" : "Hide");
  };

  $scope.hidden = function(){
    $scope.isHidden = !$scope.isHidden;
  };

}]);
```

making the html look like

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
<div class='assertive formHideShow'>
    <button ng-click="hidden()">{{text()}}</button>
</div>

<div ng-hide="isHidden">
  Hidden Text Here
</div>
```

Comment: I easily implemented the code to my project, thanks a lot